# i want to match a number of any length in awk with pattern match

Tags: awk, tomahawk

i have a number which i want to do percentile match and want the correct number in front of that with awk

```
Table 1 
    mobile
    9594047891
    9895943283
    9967545384
    9594028790


Table 2 
    display
    4047891
    95943283
    545384
    28790


out put needed      
    display Output
    404789  9594047891
    95943283    9895943283
    545384  9967545384
    28790   9594028790
```

It will be of great help if any awk specialist can solve this

i am trying to match the number which is of 10 digit with the number which is less than 10 digit

Comment: Looks like you want to join on the `id` field, not compare the display and output fields.

Comment: you're expected to show your (coding) effort so, please update the question to show the `awk` code you've tried along with the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: will a string from table1 *always* have a match in table2? can a string from table1 have multilpe matches in table2? if you answer 'yes' to either question then please update the sample inputs, and expected output, to show such cases

Comment: There are so many things this question might be about, please [edit] it to clarify your requirements and provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the short number matches the end of the long one, so you can do something like this:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == 1 { next }      # too lazy to handle the headers
    FNR == NR {
        longPhoneNumber[$1]
        next
    }
    {
        for (lpn in longPhoneNumber)
            if (lpn ~ $1"$") {
                print lpn, $1
                break
            }
    }
' Table1 Table2
```

```
9594047891 4047891
9895943283 95943283
9967545384 545384
9594028790 28790
```

Comment: its not working throwing syntax error

Comment: @MahendraSeth be more precise about the error... If your `awk` is throwing a syntax error then I guess it isn't POSIX compliant so you might try with `command -p awk ...`